# VS Code Jupyter Notebook throws an error when running R code

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

In an R jupyter notebook in VS code, when I run the cell, it throws the following error.

```
a <-1 
b <-2
```

```
ERROR: Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): <text>:1:5: unexpected input
    1: a<-1
        ^
Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): <text>:1:5: unexpected input
1: a<-1
        ^
Traceback:
```

But when I add a # symbol at the end of each line, it runs it without error.

```
a <-1 #
b <-2 #
```

Comment: Is this on Windows?

Comment: Check the Kernel and see if you are using the right one

Comment: Yes, I'm running it on windows.
The kernel has been selected as R.